# Reverse sell list (buy-in list) in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to do a buy-in list using Expresso Store? It is like a sell list except that when the user checks out the inventory will increase instead of drop and payment will be deducted from the overall sales revenue rather than increasing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to Store (or any of the EE e-commerce modules) that would allow you to do this. You will need to write an extension using Store's [developer extension hooks](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html) to create the functionality that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into how to go about doing this.